# How to fix 'Locale' has no member 'objectForKey'? Getting decimalseparator to work in my code

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField,
               shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange,
               replacementString string: String) -> Bool{
    func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        let currentLocale = NSLocale.current
        let decimalSeparator = currentLocale.objectForKey(NSLocaleDecimalSeparator) as! String
        let existingTextHasDecimalSeparator = textField.text?.rangeOfString(decimalSeparator)
        let replacementTextHasDecimalSeparator = string.rangeOfString(decimalSeparator)
        if existingTextHasDecimalSeparator != nil && replacementTextHasDecimalSeparator != nil {
            return false
        } else {
            return true
        }
```

Could someone help me figure out to fix "Value of type 'Locale'" has no member 'objectForKey' on the let decimal separator line? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try change it to `NSLocale.init(localeIdentifier: NSLocale.current.identifier).object(forKey: NSLocale.Key.decimalSeparator)`

Comment: This line of code works, but now i'm experiencing issues with the two lines below it.

Answer (score 0):

Directly use the property of `currentLocale`

```
let currentLocale = NSLocale.current
let decimalSeparator:String = currentLocale.decimalSeparator!
```

This is working for me.

```
let currentLocale = NSLocale.current
let decimalSeparator:String = currentLocale.decimalSeparator!
let existingTextHasDecimalSeparator = "text1.".range(of: decimalSeparator)
let replacementTextHasDecimalSeparator = "text2.".range(of:decimalSeparator)
if existingTextHasDecimalSeparator != nil && replacementTextHasDecimalSeparator != nil {
    print(true)
} else {
    print(false)
}
```

Comment: It got rid of that specific error code, but then the two lines under it got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

`Locale` (*Swiftified* `Foundation` class) has no member function called so but `NSLocale` does.

```
let local = Locale.current as NSLocale
local.object(forKey: NSLocale.Key.someKey)
```

that would work at least until and including `Xcode9.0`. I guess support for `NSLocale` will be dropped at some point, so we shouldn't be using it when that day comes.